# amp-boilerplate is not working

Tags: php, amp-html, x-cart

I am using x-cart 4.7.6. I have added amp tags in the .tpl files within the x-cart template (skin folder).

All tags are working, But I am getting internal server error while adding  below tags "amp-boilerplate"

```
<style amp-boilerplate>
  body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}
  @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
  @-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
  @-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
  @-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
  @keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
</style>
<noscript>
<style amp-boilerplate>
  body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}
</style>
</noscript>
```

Please provide suggestion why i am getting and how to resolve it?

Comment: What error do you get? You need to look in the server logs to see it. The browser doesn't get to know the details of an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the cause of this issue. We have to give the space between flower brackets and style.

old script:

body {-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none;}

new script:

body  {  -webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none;  }

It is working without space in other php files but not working in x-cart only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem :
you should only add @ like this :

```
    <style amp-boilerplate>
 body{ -webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}
@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}
@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
<noscript>
<style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none;
    }
</style></noscript>
```

I use visual stadio and this is work for me